# ionic app camera plugin restart the app on android v9

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic3, cordova-plugins

I develop an Ionic 4 app in which I am selecting an image from the camera or gallery module. The app works fine for all Android versions except v9 - it forces the application to restart.

```
 cameraData = [];
  constructor(private camera: Camera) {}
  openCamera(){
  const options: CameraOptions = {
    quality: 100,
    destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
    encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
    mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE
  }
  this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
   // imageData is either a base64 encoded string or a file URI
   // If it's base64 (DATA_URL):
   let base64Image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
   this.cameraData.push(base64Image);
  }, (err) => {
   // Handle error
  });
```

Comment: Your code is working fine

Comment: Thanks to reply ,I know but it not working on android v9 devices ...any suggestion ?